# PostScript == operator

Tags: operators, postscript

> The value of == is not an operator, but rather a built-in procedure.

PLRM page 526 (pdf page 540).

a built-in procedure, does this mean that this is a PostScript procedure:

```
{ something here }
```

or an actual function e.g. in Java that you have to define yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can peek at ghostscript's implementation with `/== load ==`.

Or get the book *Inside Postscript* by Frank Meritt Braswell. It has an entire chapter about how the `==` procedure works in Adobe's printer implementations.

But the simple framework is based around the properties of the `type` operator which yields a typename. More specifically, it yields an *executable name* which designates the type of the argument. So you can easily implement a type-switch with a dictionary.

```
<<
    /integertype { } % handle integer case
    /realtype { }    % handle floating-point case
    /arraytype { }   % handle array case
>> begin
5 type exec
2.0 type exec
{a b c} type exec
```

The different typed objects cause different procedures to be executed.

Using this, we can handle the different types that might be passed to the procedure.

```
/my== {
     <<
     /integertype { =string cvs print }
     /realtype { =string cvs print }
     /arraytype { dup xcheck {
                      ({ ) print {my==} forall (} ) print
                  }{
                      ([ ) print {my==} forall (] ) print
                  } }
     >> begin dup type exec
} def
```

`=string` (described in the book) is a pre-allocated 128-byte scratch buffer used by the `=` and `==` procedures for this exact purpose: supplying the argument to `cvs`.

Comment: Thanks, i've just ordered the book.

Answer (score 0):

That's a procedure.

I don't speak Java, but in PostScript if its executable, and its not an operator (part of the language) then you have to define it yourself.

Note that in PostScript it is also possible to redefine operators, so just because it has the name of an operator, doesn't mean it **is** an operator, it might still be a procedure.

Comment: so that 'built-in procedure' is actually a postscript procedure in the systemdict?

Comment: Its a PostScript procedure, rather than an operator, I'm not certain its defined in systemdict, I don't have a PLRM to hand as I'm travelling at the moment.